# Unhandled Runtime Error TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of undefined (Next.js, React, AWS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, aws-amplify

I am trying to follow this tutorial [here](https://dev.to/aws-builders/create-an-online-c-v-with-nextjs-aws-amplify-tailwind-css-4dhh?signin=true).

And I am doing it exactly like the guy says. But every time I am getting this same error:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of undefined
```

```
pages/index.js (20:57) @ _callee$

  18 |   });
  19 |   setIsLoading(false);
> 20 |   setListMainDetails(mainDetails.data.listMainDetailss.items[0]);
     |                                                       ^
  21 | }
  22 | if(isLoading || !mainDetails) {
  23 |   return <p>..Loading</p>
```

And I literally don't know what to do anymore.

If I build from scratch or if I clone the guy's [repo](https://github.com/Rolando-Barbella/online-dev-cv) and just authenticate with my amplify credentials, I get the same error.

Here's the full `index.js` code:

```js
import Head from 'next/head';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Link from 'next/link';
import { API } from 'aws-amplify';
import { listMainDetails } from '../graphql/queries'

export default function Home() {
  let [mainDetails, setListMainDetails] = useState(null);
  let [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchListMainDetailss()
  },[])
  
  async function fetchListMainDetailss() {
    const mainDetails = await API.graphql({
      query: listMainDetails
    });
    setIsLoading(false);
    setListMainDetails(mainDetails.data.listMainDetailss.items[0]);
  }
  if(isLoading || !mainDetails) {
    return <p>..Loading</p>
  }
  return (
    <div className="relative py-3 sm:max-w-xl sm:mx-auto">
      <Head>
        <title>My online C.V</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <div className="mt-5 md:mt-5 md:col-span-2">
        <div className="bg-white shadow overflow-hidden sm:rounded-lg">
          <div className="px-4 py-5 sm:px-6">
            <h3 className="text-lg leading-6 font-medium text-gray-900">
              My Online C.V
            </h3>
          </div>
          <div className="border-t border-gray-200">
            <dl>
              <div className="bg-gray-50 px-4 py-5 sm:grid sm:grid-cols-3 sm:gap-4 sm:px-6">
                <dt className="text-sm font-medium text-gray-500">
                  Name
                </dt>
                <dd className="mt-1 text-sm text-gray-900 sm:mt-0 sm:col-span-2">
                  {mainDetails.name}
                </dd>
              </div>
              <div className="bg-white px-4 py-5 sm:grid sm:grid-cols-3 sm:gap-4 sm:px-6">
                <dt className="text-sm font-medium text-gray-500">
                  Last Name
                </dt>
                <dd className="mt-1 text-sm text-gray-900 sm:mt-0 sm:col-span-2">
                  {mainDetails.lastName}
                </dd>
              </div>
              <div className="bg-gray-50 px-4 py-5 sm:grid sm:grid-cols-3 sm:gap-4 sm:px-6">
                <dt className="text-sm font-medium text-gray-500">
                  Email address
                </dt>
                <dd className="mt-1 text-sm text-gray-900 sm:mt-0 sm:col-span-2">
                  {mainDetails.email}
                </dd>
              </div>
              <div className="bg-white px-4 py-5 sm:grid sm:grid-cols-3 sm:gap-4 sm:px-6">
                <dt className="text-sm font-medium text-gray-500">
                  Location
                </dt>
                <dd className="mt-1 text-sm text-gray-900 sm:mt-0 sm:col-span-2">
                  {mainDetails.location}
                </dd>
              </div>
              <div className="bg-gray-50 px-4 py-5 sm:grid sm:grid-cols-3 sm:gap-4 sm:px-6">
                <dt className="text-sm font-medium text-gray-500">
                  Description
                </dt>
                <dd className="mt-1 text-sm text-gray-900 sm:mt-0 sm:col-span-2">
                  {mainDetails.description}
                </dd>
               </div>
               <div className="bg-white px-4 py-5 sm:grid sm:grid-cols-3 sm:gap-4 sm:px-6">
                <Link href={`/edit/${mainDetails.id}`}>
                  <div className="inline-flex justify-center py-2 px-4 border border-transparent shadow-sm text-sm font-medium rounded-md text-white bg-indigo-600 hover:bg-indigo-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500">
                    Edit
                  </div>
                </Link>
              </div>
            </dl>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Try to understand the problem. It says that `mainDetails.data.listMainDetailss.items[0]` -  the variables before the `items[0]` is undefined, meaning no data. Add type safety checks and then set

Comment: Is the `API.graphql(...)` call returning the expected output?

Comment: @KarthikR i can't understand a thing you've said, my dude.
Could you help me codewise? What do i have to type to get it working?

Comment: @juliomalves No.
Nothin is working as expected. Like the guy describes in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use optional chaining syntax, like this:

```js
setListMainDetails(mainDetails.data.listMainDetailss?.items?.[0]);
```

Just add `?.` symbol if you want to access object data that sometimes `undefined`
Or you can check the data is exist before set state happen

```js
// Check if items is not empty array
if(mainDetails?.data?.listMainDetailss?.items?.length) {
  setListMainDetails(mainDetails.data.listMainDetailss.items[0]);
}
```

Comment: I tried both. And none worked, i think.

If i set the one to check if the data exist before set state, the error from NextJS stop appearing, and the page gets rendered, but on the console i got a lot of errors: https://i.imgur.com/L6QxyvK.png

Comment: Are you sure that "listMainDetailss" is not typo, and should be "listMainDetails"? Cause it seems like you are accessing items from undefined "listMainDetailss"

Comment: is not a typo, i defined the function like this everywhere.

I did it this way cause in the graphql query i have a "listMainDetails" with just one 's'

Comment: But in your code i see this typo, "setListMainDetails(mainDetails.data.listMainDetailss.items[0]);", double "ss"